# Ruby-Rails net-ldap search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap, ldap-query

I want to be able to determine if a user is a memberOf a specific group as well as a couple other attributes available on the active directory. I know that the authentication and binding is working as intended, however, I keep getting two warnings:

`warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call`

`warning: The called method tcp is defined here`

Since these are warnings, I wouldn't expect them to affect the output that I'm looking for.

I want to list out the attributes and the values for the search query, but when I run the code, I get the warnings, followed by "Bind succeeded!", and then the program finishes executing. I've tried changing the query, changing the attributes that I'm searching for, and ensuring that they were named correctly. I have posted the code below:

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => HOST, # your LDAP host name or IP goes here,
                      :port => PORT, # your LDAP host port goes here,
                      :encryption => :simple_tls,
                      :base =>  BASE# the base of your AD tree goes here,
                      :auth => {
                        :method => :simple,
                        :username => "#{login}@#{myDomain}", # a user w/sufficient privileges to read from AD goes here,
                        :password => PASSWORD # the user's password goes here
                      }


search_param = @username
result_attrs = ["sAMAccountName", "displayName", "mail", "memberOf"] # Whatever you want to bring back in your result set goes here

# Build filter
search_filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("sAMAccountName", search_param)

# Execute search
if ldap.bind
    puts "Bind succeeded!"
    ldap.search(:filter => search_filter, :attributes => result_attrs) do |entry| 
        puts "DN: #{entry.dn}"
        entry.each do |attr, values|
            puts ".......#{attr}:"
            values.each do |value|
              puts "#{value}\n"
            end
        end
    end
else
    puts "Failure to bind"
end
```

A couple problems I feel could be causing this issue is that I don't have the required authentication to search for users in the directory, or the users don't exist (I am searching for my own username, so it should exist, therefore I'm leaning to first theory). Thank you!